# Listening to Mediaplayer object's events through UiAutomator

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-uiautomator

I am able to launch the Music Player using the layouts etc. NowI am trying to figure out a way, if my UiAutomator test can listen in on the already launched Android Music Player's events- something like the listeners that the Media Player class provides.

This is needed because I want to figure out a few things like when the song ends(figure out when the EOS happens) ,was the seek successful etc..

All help is appreciated.

Thanks!